# How can show a div when input has a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input text that and a hide div.

I want to show the div when the input text has a value.

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vyc7N/181/

```
<label for="db">Type whatever</label>
<input type="text"name="amount"  />

<div id="yeah" style="display:none;">
 <input type="submit"   />
</div>
```

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: look at the change/key event handler

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P78Wc/ many ways you can do this but atleast try some `:)`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/duCJ3/1/ - `$('input[name="amount"]').bind('keyup change', function(){
    $('#yeah').toggle(this.value.length)
})`

Comment: Looks like your question garnered some downvotes due to the apparent lack of research effort. Btw, nice Lost Canvas avatar. `=]`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/vyc7N/185/

Comment: But why i received points down?

Comment: @CarlitosMorales quoting myself: "Looks like your question garnered some downvotes due to the apparent lack of research effort."

Comment: Oh god ok..no problem is because I don't know much about javascript but thanks for helping

Comment: @CarlitosMorales you currently have +2 -4 votes, translating it to reputation it is 2*5 - 4*2, you're actually gaining some reputation even with the negative score.

Comment: How could be using prototype? How could be using prototype? jsfiddle.net/P78Wc/2 please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write the code in keyup event of textbox to get the length of text entered in it.

```
$('input[name=amount]').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val().length)
    $('#yeah').show();
  else
    $('#yeah').hide();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q7ktX/)**

you can also use `.toggle()` instead of using `.show`/`.hide()`:

```
  $('input[name=amount]').keyup(function(){
     $('#yeah').toggle($(this).val().length);
  });
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` Seriously??

Comment: You should bind both `keyup` and `change`, as `keyup` is not fired by most if not all mobile devices.

Comment: You should listen to the `input` event, since it works with IMEs.

Comment: Why do people still answer with `keyup` and `change` in 2014..? No love for the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input).

Comment: Yeah, if you don't need IE < 9 support, you can use the `input` event.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara IE<9 can fallback to the `propertychange` event.

Comment: Actually, IE9 has a bug " IE 9 does not fire an input event when the user removes characters from input filled by keyboard, cut, or drag operations." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input.

Comment: @CarlitosMorales: not sure with prototype syntax  :/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[name=amount]').bind('keyup change', function(){
if(!$(this).val())
    $("#yeah").css('display', 'none');
else
    $("#yeah").css('display', '');
});
```

Comment: Not a downvoter but that could be for not having any js try before asking!

Answer (score 1):

### This is pure javascript and DOM, no jQuery

You could use `onkeyup()`:

```
<label>Type whatever</label>
<input id='inptOne' type="text" name="amount" onkeyup="myFunction()" />

<div id="yeah" style="display:none">
    <input type="submit" />
</div>

<script>
//if input has some value will show the button
  window.myFunction = function() {
  //alert('it ran!');
  var hasValue = document.getElementById('inptOne').value;
  if (!!hasValue) {
    document.getElementById('yeah').style.display = 'inline';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('yeah').style.display = 'none';
  };
 };
</script>
```

[Click Here for jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blueprinter/fTTQr/)

Comment: For some reason, jsfiddle doesn't work right.  It's not the codes fault, it's jsfiddle.  If you use the code otherwise it will work.  But I did change the jsfiddle, so it does work on jsfiddle.   [Code Here jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blueprinter/q7ktX/11/)

Comment: @SandyGood , but subit doesnt hide is i erase what i typed

Comment: True.  Here is a version with `onkeyup` that both displays and hides the submit button.  [Click Here for jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blueprinter/q7ktX/14/)

Answer (score 1):

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7ktX/12/)

Use following logic : If after trimming there is some value , then show else hide.

```
$('input[name=amount]').keyup(function(){
  if($.trim($(this).val())!='')
    $('#yeah').show();
  else
    $('#yeah').hide();
});
```